# tikz package not found in repository

Tags: latex, texlive

I'm trying to install package `tikz`.
I was using texlive 2019, and got this error message when trying to install `tikz` via `tlmgr`:

```
tlmgr install: package tikz not present in repository
```

I purged the texlive instalattion, and installed texlive 2022 via:

```bash
wget http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
tar -xf install-tl-unx.tar.gz
cd install-tl-*
sudo ./install-tl
```

I tried again, but I got the same error...
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you've solved this by now or not, but looks like [the package on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) is actually called `pgf`.